# How to compare the assortativity of two distinct networks?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, social-network

In the context of Social Network Analysis, I have two different social networks (in fact both are subgraphs of the same graph, but all the edges are distinct) and I would like to find a rigourous tool to compare their assortativity coefficients (associated to the same set of categories).

In other words, these I obtain two assortativity coefficients which are equal to 26.97% and 30.24%, and I would like to assess the significance of the difference.

Is there any kind of statistical hypothesis test I could perform in order to do it?